# Drop a SQL Server login using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I can successfully create a SQL Server login using VB.NET, but I am facing issues with dropping the login. There are no syntax errors, but login and user are not getting dropped.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
Protected Sub Button_Del_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button_Del.Click
    Dim constrDel As String
    Dim SrvDel As String
    Dim DbDel As String
    Dim LoginDel As String
    Dim DeleteSQL As String

        SrvDel = DropDownList_Instance.SelectedItem.Text
        DbDel = DropDownList_Database.SelectedItem.Text
        constrDel = "Data Source=" & SrvDel & ";Initial Catalog=" & DbDel & ";Integrated Security=true"
        LoginDel = TextBox_Login.Text
        Using Con2 As New SqlConnection(constrDel)
            Con2.Open()
            Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ChkLogin, Con2)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

                DeleteSQL = "Drop Login [" + LoginDel + "] Drop User [" + LoginDel + "] "
                dr.Close()
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Con2.Close()
                MsgBox("Login Deleted")
```

Comment: There's no command text applied to the commmand object so you're not actually using the DeleteSQL query you've built.

Comment: Oh thank you, no idea how I missed that. I'm on track now, thanks for your time!